# How to use addEventListener

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I was making a script that creates div elements each time a button is pressed. Originally I had the function called inline with the `onclick` attribute, but jslint doesn't like that so I moved it out and instead tried to use `addEventListener("click",function());`

I've never used `addEventListener()` before so I'm not even sure I am using it correctly.

The problem is that it creates one `div` when the page loads and won't do anything when the button is pressed.

Thank you in advance.

here is what I have:

```
<body>
<form>
    <textarea id="a"></textarea>    
    <br>
    <input value="button" type="button">
</form>
<div id="content">
</div>
<script>
    /*jslint browser:true */
    function createEntry(text) {
        "use strict";

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class", "test");
        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
    }
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    input.addEventListener("click", createEntry(document.getElementById('a').value));
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the event listener like this

```
input.addEventListener("click", function(){
    createEntry(document.getElementById('a').value);
});
```

as it stands, you're passing the result of `createEntry` as an event listener, not the function itself

More information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 7):

Change this line

```
input.addEventListener("click", createEntry(document.getElementById('a').value));
```

into

```
input.addEventListener("click", function(){
createEntry(document.getElementById('a').value);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using a JavaScript library like jQuery for event handling and DOM manipulation, to be browser safe and for uniformity.

You can use the event handlers in jQuery like the following:

```
$(<element_selector>).on("click", function (event) {
     // your code here...
});
```

Comment: I knew how to do it with JQuery, but I wanted to improve my Javascript skills by writing without it. You bring up a good point about cross browser safety, though. Thanks :]