# WebMIDI simple Visuals?

Tags: css, midi

I would like to use Webmidi to let a simple black box to turn white for a short time when a specific MIDI note, or any note from a specific MIDI channel is incoming.
I have this code but i don't know how to trig the css color change. Thanks!

```
WebMidi.enable(function(err) { 

if (err) console.log("WebMidi could not be enabled");

var input = WebMidi.inputs[0];


// Listening for a 'note on' message (on channel 1 only) 
input.addEventListener('noteon', 1,
  function(e){ console.log(e); }
);

// Listening to other messages works the same way 
input.addListener('noteoff', "all,"
  function(e){ console.log(e); }
);


}

);
```

Comment: This is not WebMIDI API, I guess it is [webmidi.js](https://github.com/djipco/webmidi). You should to mention it. Also, your question is not about WebMidi, it is about DOM. Learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom function that sets the colour of the div.  The event listener then triggers the function.  This may help:

[How to use addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771025/how-to-use-addeventlistener)

Comment: Thanks. I'm a beginner and i don't understand very well how to do the syntax to connect the input.addEventListener to the script that will change the div color

Comment: Well, you should give the div a unique id like this <div id="ColourChangingDiv"> ... </div>.  You can then write JavaScript code that references this unique div id and alters its CSS style properties.

Comment: Ok, Thanks i will try

Answer (score 0):

using [jquery](https://jquery.com/) you can set css attributes like background color using the css() function

for example:

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
```