# want to call a javascript function through add event listener in td of a row

Tags: javascript, laravel, html-table

I  have done the following.

```
<td class="text-center"><a href="#" title="" id="signal_<?=$rs['signal_id']?>"  addEventListener('click','editSignal(this)') data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send_distress_modal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="#" title="" id="signal_<?=$rs['signal_id']?>" onclick="deleteSignal(this);"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
```

I had it done using onclick but want to do the same using addeventlistener('click,'anyFunction').
Because when I use onclick it gives the folowing error;

```
VM7707 log:330 Uncaught ReferenceError: editSignal is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM7707 log:330)
```

These are the functions below there is some problem with both they give error when clicked. Can't figure out what is the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editSignal(obj) {
    // alert(obj.id);
    var obj_id = obj.id;
    var id = obj_id.split("_");
    console.log(id);
    let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send_distress_signal',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {edit_signal_id: id[1],
        //  _token: _token
         }},
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#description').val(result['description']);
        $('#resType').val(result['resource_type']);
        $('#res').val(result['resource']);
        $('#resource_hidden').val(result['resource']);
        $('#location').val(result['location']);
        $('#edit_flag_signal').val(result['signal_id']);
        populateResource();
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });

}

function deleteSignal(obj) {
    // alert(obj.id);
    var obj_id = obj.id;
    var id = obj_id.split("_");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/sendDistress_action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {del_signal_id: id[1]},
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        if(result=="Success"){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            alert("Some error occured");
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
}

$('#distress_btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    $('#description').val('');
    $('#resType').val('');
    $('#res').val('');
    $('#resource_hidden').val('');
    $('#location').val('');
    $('#edit_flag_signal').val('0');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to write `addEventListener` code into `<script>` not inline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771025/how-to-use-addeventlistener)

Comment: <td class="text-center"><a href="#" title="" id="signal_<?=$rs['signal_id']?> "data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send_distress_modal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>

Comment: Have you got a Javascript function called editSignal somewhere? If so onclick="editSignal(this)" should have worked. Your use of addEventListener in that context is incorrect.

Comment: I can't use script tag in this line?

Comment: Yes I have the fuction but it says VM8855 log:330 Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteSignal is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM8855 log:330)

Comment: @HamzaKhan — In what line? There's no `<script>` anywhere in your question.

Comment: I have edited the code above thats the script I'm using and it gives the error I have mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

These are just test codes for the example. Focus on the `<script>` parts.
If you want to use addEventListener you have to use it in a script section by the event target which is well noted in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      td {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var td1ClickCount = 0;
    function customClickFunction() {
      clickCount += 1;
      console.log("clickCount : " + clickCount);
    }
    function editSignal(element) {
      console.log("editSignal From id : " + element.id);
    }
    function deleteSignal(element) {
      console.log("deleteSignal From id : " + element.id);
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="td1" class="text-center">
          <a href="#" title="" id="signal_1" onclick="editSignal(this);">
            <i class="fa fa-edit">signal_1</i>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td id="td2" class="text-center">
          <a href="#" title="" id="signal_2" onclick="deleteSignal(this);">
            <i class="fa fa-trash">signal_2</i>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //EventTarget.addEventListener(type, listener, ...);
    document.getElementById("td1").addEventListener('click', function(event){
      td1ClickCount += 1;
      console.log(event.target + " click count: " + td1ClickCount);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly avoid adding the 'addEventListener' in the HTML element but use in the  tag either in the same HTML or external js file. I noticed few issues in the HTML and javascript code so I suggest you the following change in the HTML and Javascript code. I'm sure it will work fine.

- Don't use the id="signal_..." but use row-id="signal_..." this way both edit and delete elements will not have the same Id.
  The same Id doesn't follow the HTML standard rules.
- Remove the 'addEventListener' from the HTML element and use the alternative way in the javascript section.
- Add the class attributes and register the event listener with this class attrib which also follows the HTML standard rules.

```html
<td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="editSignal" title="" row-id="signal_<?=$rs['signal_id']?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send_distress_modal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
<td class="text-center"><a href="#" title="" class="deleteSignal" row-id="signal_<?=$rs['signal_id']?>" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
```

Then use the following javascript function in your script section.

```js
$(document).on('click','.editSignal',function(){
    var obj_id = $(this).attr('row-id');
    //alert(obj_id);
    var id = obj_id.split("_");
    console.log(id);
    //return;
    let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send_distress_signal',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {edit_signal_id: id[1]},
        //  _token: _token
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#description').val(result['description']);
        $('#resType').val(result['resource_type']);
        $('#res').val(result['resource']);
        $('#resource_hidden').val(result['resource']);
        $('#location').val(result['location']);
        $('#edit_flag_signal').val(result['signal_id']);
        populateResource();
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});

$(document).on('click','.deleteSignal',function(){
    var obj_id = $(this).attr('row-id');
    var id = obj_id.split("_");
    console.log(id);
    //return;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/sendDistress_action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {del_signal_id: id[1]},
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        if(result=="Success"){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            alert("Some error occured");
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Hopefully, it will work now. If it still doesn't work then please send me the HTML and Javascript code to review and I will provide you the solution accordingly.